# Get all rows between start and end flag

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, grouping, window-functions

I've got a similar data structure

```
Parameter | Value | DateTime
----------------------------
Switch    | "on"  | 2019-10-13 15:01:25
Temp      | 25    | 2019-10-13 15:01:37
Pressure  | 1006  | 2019-10-13 15:01:53
...
Temp      | 22    | 2019-10-13 15:04:41
Switch    | "off" | 2019-10-13 15:04:59
...
Switch    | "on"  | 2019-10-13 17:14:51
Temp      | 27    | 2019-10-13 17:15:07
...
Switch    | "off" | 2019-10-13 17:17:43
```

Between each pair of Switch "on" and "off" I have to calculate the values for the parameters, i.e. average or max/min and so on. How can I get the different data sets to have multiple groups for the calculation?

I think this should be solvable with
- Stored Procedure (statement?)
- SSIS package (how?)
- .NET application.

What might be the best way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

This is the full structure of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [schema].[foo]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Group] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [Parameter] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Type] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Value] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [Unit] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

    // Only for logging. No logic for the use case.
    [InsertedTimestampUtc] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GetUtcDate()),
    [IsProcessed] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
)
```

Comment: Is there a column for determining order of records like a datetime or incrementing id? Please also include, from your sample data here, your desired results so we can better understand what you are after.

Comment: Your data structure is a table ? or results from joining different tables?What is your expected output?

Comment: Yes. The table contains a date field. I appended it to the example.

Comment: @mburm can you share the structure of your table ?

Comment: The source it's one table. As result I need for each group of rows (between on/off) for each parameter exact one calculated value. This could be a row with all parameters as columns. It's also possible to have multiple lines with pairs of parameter and calculated value. The "key" is the min datetime of the group. Something like 2019-10-13 15:01:25 | Temp | 24; 2019-10-13 15:01:25 | Pressure | 1008...

Comment: Are the rows with `Switch` = `'On'` always follow the rows with `Switch` = `'Off'`?

Comment: Yes. This is a requirement that first the on row comes and after this an off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the next approach may help to get the expected results:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    [DateTime] datetime,
    [Parameter] varchar(50),
    [Value] varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
    ([DateTime], [Parameter], [Value])
VALUES
    ('2019-10-13T15:01:25', 'Switch',   'on'),
    ('2019-10-13T15:01:37', 'Temp',     '25'),
    ('2019-10-13T15:01:53', 'Pressure', '1006'),
    ('2019-10-13T15:04:41', 'Temp',     '22'),
    ('2019-10-13T15:04:59', 'Switch',   'off'),
    ('2019-10-13T17:14:51', 'Switch',   'on'),
    ('2019-10-13T17:15:07', 'Temp',     '27'),
    ('2019-10-13T17:17:43', 'Switch',   'off')
```

Statement:

```
;WITH ChangesCTE AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN [Parameter] = 'Switch' AND [Value] = 'on' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ChangeIndex
    FROM #Data
), GroupsCTE AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(ChangeIndex) OVER (ORDER BY [DateTime]) AS GroupIndex
    FROM ChangesCTE
)
SELECT [GroupIndex], [Parameter], AVG(TRY_CONVERT(int, [Value]) * 1.0) AS [AvgValue]
FROM GroupsCTE
WHERE [Parameter] <> 'Switch'
GROUP BY [GroupIndex], [Parameter]
```

Results:

```
GroupIndex  Parameter   AvgValue
1           Pressure    1006.000000
1           Temp        23.500000
2           Temp        27.000000
```